# Unable to run a react-router example locally while it runs successfully on CodeSandbox

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I'm trying to execute the [react-router's example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) locally. But when I do, I face the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:18)
    at t (bootstrap 89d91d26cff14f347b23:19)
    at bootstrap 89d91d26cff14f347b23:62
    at bootstrap 89d91d26cff14f347b23:62
```

It's in the case that I've managed to run it on [CodeSandbox successfully](https://codesandbox.io/s/1krx3j31l). So I simplified the code to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

const AuthExample = () => (
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
)

ReactDOM.render(<AuthExample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The simplified version works. In my `package.json` I've got:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "3.5.1",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "socket.io": "2.0.4"
  },
```

I know it's hard to debug a code without having access to it but is there any pointers one can give me what the problem could be?

Comment: What kind of package manager do you use?I have the same error, when I try "npm install react-router" intstead of "yarn add react-router", because create-react-app uses yarn as default npm manager.